# How do I go about inserting an element count when generating xml document

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to generate a XML doc from a CSV. How do I go about inserting the element number into the xml. So for instance: If the CSV file has 10 messages, each message would get a number referencing it's sequence in the CSV file. I'd imagine there is someway to reference the index of the range variable but not sure how to do that using LINQ or other means. Thanks!

```
        LoadCSV();
        if (_loadedCSV == null)
            return;

        XElement xmlFile = new XElement("Root",
            from str in _loadedCSV
            let fields = str.Split(',')
            select new XElement("Track",
                new XAttribute("Message Number", <<ELEMENT NUMBER>>),
                new XElement("Date", fields[0]),
                new XElement("Time", fields[1]),
                new XElement("Message", fields[2])));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `Select` overload with element and index, [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__). Unfortunately it's available only in LINQ Method Syntax, but not in LINQ Query one:

```
    LoadCSV();
    if (_loadedCSV == null)
        return;

    XElement xmlFile = new XElement("Root",
        (from str in _loadedCSV
        select str.Split(','))
        // .Where(fields => fields.Length >= 3) 
        .Select((fields,index) => new XElement("Track",
            new XAttribute("Message Number", (index+1).ToString()),
            new XElement("Date", fields.Length > 0 ? fields[0] : ""),
            new XElement("Time", fields.Length > 1 ? fields[1] : ""),
            new XElement("Message", fields.Length > 2 ? fields[2] : ""))));
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried the code and for some reason I get an array out of bounds exception.

Comment: @Petro, I've updated my answer with the checks for the case when not all columns are filled.

Comment: Upon further inspection today I realized my csv file was being appended instead of overwritten during generation. This was the source of my problems with the elements not being added properly. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
           XElement xmlFile = new XElement("Root",
             _loadedCSV.Select((x,i) => new XElement("Track", new object[] {
                new XAttribute("Message Number", i + 1),
                x.Split(new char[] {','})
                .Select((y, j) => (j == 0) ? new XElement("Date", y) :
                                      (j == 1) ? new XElement("Time", y) :
                                      new XElement("Message", y)
                )})));
```

Comment: This seems to work but for whatever reason it goes from working as expected to then failing to parse the message.
<Time>14:18:09Z</Time>
 <Time>System.String[]</Time> 
<Time>Hi this is my test string</Time>. Almost as it goes out of bounds like Renat's answer above. I'm probably just better off doing this the old fashion way.

Comment: the CSV file must have some rows that do not have three columns.  You may just have a blank line at beginning or end of the file.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. Not sure what I was looking at yesterday but it turned out my file csv file was being appended instead of overwritten causing some lines to only have 2 elements. Regenerated my csv and it works fine. Thank you for your help!